# How do I set userprincipalname of sts issuer?

Tags: wcf, wcf-security, federation

Simple question for MS insiders and/or WCF gurus:

How do I specify by *config* the userprincipalname of the sts issuer in a client binding to a service using WS-Federation? (This is so the client can auth to IP-STS using Windows Auth)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, don't know why I couldn't find this before, but first thing Monday morning the answer pops up immediately:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347735.aspx

The issuer element of the wsfederation is an endpoint config that allows you to set the user principal name within it.

The schema from the link above is here:

```
<issuer address="Uri" >
   <headers>
      <add name="String"
                 namespace="String" />
   </headers>
   <identity>
           <certificate encodedValue="String"/>
      <certificateReference findValue="String" 
         isChainIncluded="Boolean"
         storeName="AddressBook/AuthRoot/CertificateAuthority/Disallowed/My/Root/TrustedPeople/TrustedPublisher"
         storeLocation="LocalMachine/CurrentUser"
                  x509FindType=System.Security.Cryptography.X509certificates.X509findtype/>
      <dns value="String"/>
      <rsa value="String"/>
      <servicePrincipalName value="String"/>
      <usePrincipalName value="String"/>
   </identity>
</issuer>
```